# code inside #ifdef is included in runtime or during compilation itself?

Tags: c++, c

I am using `#define ENABLE_FLAG` inside C++ code and correspondingly trying to include a section of code, while `ENABLE_FLAG` is defined.

My question is, the particular set of code inside

```
#ifdef ENABLE_FLAG
....setofcode....
#endif
```

is evaluated during runtime through `#ifdef` check or compiler itself sees the `ENABLE_FLAG` during compilation and includes the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#ifdef` and all those other things you see with a `#` as the first character on the line are "C preprocessor directives."  These are handled even before compilation proper.  So there will be no runtime decision made at all--the enabled/disabled block of code is decided at the earliest part of the build process.

Comment: Lol you both did the same thing because of the `#`

Comment: Yeah I had never seen that "feature" before - apparently starting a line with # makes it into giant heading text even if there's no space after the # and the line itself is very long.  Who knew.

Answer (score 2):

`#define` settings are compile time, and persist during run time.